Orbits under the automorphism group of projective space
Let $\mathbb{P}^d_K$ be projective space of dimension $d\geq 1$ over an infinite field $K$. Let $x\in\mathbb{P}^d_K$ with $\dim\overline{\lbrace x\rbrace}=n\leq d-1$.
My question: is the set $\lbrace g(x)\mid g\in \operatorname{Aut}_K(\mathbb{P}^d_K)\rbrace$ infinite? If not, is it true for certain $K$, $n$ and $d$?
I post this question 9 days ago on MSE, nobody answers yet. Any comment or help is much appreciated.

Yes.  The automorphism group is $PGL(d+1)$, and it acts transitively on (closed) points of $P^d$.  Then for a proper subvariety $X \subset P^d$, its translates under the group action cover all of $P^d$.  But $P^d$ isn't a finite union of proper subvarieties, since $K$ is infinite.

@JackHuizenga: I think your argument is not quite correct: the automorphism group does not act transitively on closed points in general and $X$ need not have any rational points. (The statement is of course true, but a little more is needed to deal with non-algebraically closed fields.)

You're right, my argument works if K is algebraically closed.

@JackHuizenga@naf Thanks for both great comments. Would it be possible that you post your idea as a detailed answer when $K$ is not necessarily algebraic closed field?

It's notationally a bit easier to work with $\mathbb{A}^n_K$ instead of $\mathbb{P}^n_K$, and then only work with automorphisms of $\mathbb{A}^n_K$ that come from $\mathbb{P}^n_K$.
Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}_K^n$ be a proper subvariety.  Pick an algebraic closure $L$ of $K$ and a point $p\in X \subset \mathbb{A}_L^n$.  Then $\operatorname{Aut}_K(\mathbb{A}^n_K)$ contains all the translations by vectors in $K^n$, so the varieties in the orbit of $X$ contain all the points of the form $p + K^n$.  If there were only finitely many varieties in the orbit, their union would be a proper subvariety of $\mathbb{A}_L^n$.  In particular, there would be a nonzero polynomial in $L[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ vanishing on their union.
But, a nonzero polynomial in $L[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ can't vanish on all of $p+K^n$ since $K$ is infinite.  I.e., $p+K^n$ is Zariski dense in $\mathbb{A}_L^n$.  This is an easy induction on $n$.

Here's a different, more algebraically flavored argument, which shows that this result already (almost) holds for the action of the torus $\mathbb{T}_{\mathbb{P}^d}(K) := \{\text{diagonal matrices}\} \subseteq \operatorname{PGL}_{d+1}(K)$.
Proposition. If $\eta \in \mathbb{P}^d_K$ has finite orbit under the action of $\mathbb{T}_{\mathbb{P}^d}(K)$, then $\eta \mathbin{\hat{=}} \langle x_{i_1},\dots,x_{i_{d-n}}\rangle_{K[x_0,\dots,x_d]}$ is a coordinate subspace.
Proof.  Let $\{\eta = \eta_1,\dots,\eta_k\}$ be the orbit of $\eta$. Let $I = I\left(\bigcup_i \eta_i \right) \subseteq K[x_0,\dots,x_d]$. This is a torus-fixed ideal, hence monomial [Eisenbud, Thm. 15.23.a.]; this uses $|K| = \infty$. It is also radical by construction, so the primary decomposition is an intersection of ideals of coordinate subspaces. On the other hand, $\eta$ itself corresponds to a prime ideal in the primary decomposition $\bigcap_i I(\eta_i)$, it must be a coordinate subspace. $\square$
To solve your original problem, assume $\eta \in \mathbb{P}^d_K$ has a finite $\operatorname{PGL}_{d+1}(K)$-orbit. Then it is a coordinate subspace, but $\operatorname{PGL}_{d+1}(K)$ acts transitively on linear subspaces defined over $K$, a contradiction (unless $\overline{\{\eta\}} = \mathbb{P}^d_K$).

I am really sorry I could only accept one answer. Your both answers are perfectly solve my question!
